# Get firebase data into a google sheet in real time

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to get data of my firebase project into a real time google sheet. I have tried a few methods by googling including (https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script) but none was a success. Any lead would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

```
function getData() {

  var firebaseUrl = "https://network-maintenance-app-d54c7.firebaseio.com/";
  var secret = "0tgfUYUo8oDJI6lNWKhKSFd8uOPhlig7XJ0epwsu";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, secret);
  var data = base.getData();
  Logger.log(data);
}
```